# Does Electrum Daemon give a transaction id even when balance is too low?

Tags: electrum, daemon

Occasionally in my database I have a transaction id output from electrum for some bitcoin sent but that transaction id is invalid. If the balance is too low on electrum and I try to send an amount greater than the wallet balance will electrum still give me a bitcoin transaction id?

This wreaks havoc on my service because it appears that transactions happen when in fact those txids are invalid.  This wasn't happening before, but now it appears to happen a few times a day (with a volume of a few hundred transactions - everything works, except for those occasional invalid trx)

Comment: What do you mean that it's invalid? Is it just not getting into the chain? Can you give an example of one of these transactions?

Comment: yes, its just not getting to the chain - if you look one up it says not found on block explorers - except blockchain.info which will claim it  is a double spend